# loopback custom query did not give response

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopback

my loopback custom query cannot give response after some time. below is my code.

```
var ds = tbljourney.dataSource;
        ds.connector.query("select * from user where  email='" + data.email + "'"
        , function (err, user) {
                user = user[0];

            console.log("user", user);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);

            }
            else if (user) { 
   }
  });
```

some time it give a response but after 50 or 60 attemps its stuck

Answer (score 0):

try to run your queries using the method below. Here's I'm connecting to an Oracle database. A lot of concat gets messy.

```
Model.remoteMethod(data,cb){      
  var app = require('../server');
  var ds = app.datasources.newDatasource;

  var sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SITE_ID=:param1 AND "+
    "(DESTINATION=:param2 OR USERNAME=:param2 )";
  var params = [param1, param2];
  ds.connector.execute(sql, params, function(err, result){
    if (err) console.error("error: " + err);
    cb(err, result);
  });
}
```